# how to turn WiFi off using python on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, wifi

I need to turn the WiFi off using python on Windows 10, but only turn off WiFi and not disable the adapter or just disconnecting from the network I am connected to (Software Off, but Hardware On).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn WiFi off using Python on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246527/turn-wifi-off-using-python-on-windows-10)

Comment: No, its disabling the adapter, i need that it would only turn off WiFi

Answer (score 1):

Your question might be answered by this other question which is quite similar :
[Turn WiFi off using Python on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246527/turn-wifi-off-using-python-on-windows-10)

I'm not sure if this actually answers your question since you don't want to disable the adapter, but it does use the adapter to turn off wifi.

I can't find any other way to turn wifi on or off without the adapter. Therefore, it probably is not possible to turn wifi on or off without it. It looks like you can't do this in any other language either, according to this other issue where someone wanted to know how to disable wifi using powershell. Apparently, you can only use Windows 10's interface to do this. I hope this helped.

[How to switch WiFi state on/off with PowerShell & Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486244/how-to-switch-wifi-state-on-off-with-powershell-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: No, its disabling the adapter, i need that it would only turn off WiFi